# What can I use take a reference for both fstream and cout?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void writeit( ostream& os, const char* text) {
    os << text;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("text.txt");
    writeit(myfile, "Hello world");
    writeit(cout, "Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

It's working, but it is very strange. Is there any better solutions to write to the screen and to the file in the same function without template?

Comment: You could pass a container of `ostream` references, or make a helper class that opens a file and prints to it and `cout`. I'm not sure what you mean by "it is very strange". Do you mean that it requires to lines of code?

Comment: No, it's not very strange at all. This is the correct approach. Give yourself some time. In a couple of years it will not seem so strange at all, and you will actually think that this is the most beautiful aspect of C++. Wanna bet?

Comment: This is a nice example of polymorphism - the function takes a reference to a base class and you can pass a derived class to it. Just works!

Comment: That is because `cout` and a `fstream` are both `ostream`s, since both of them inherit from `ostream`. See the diagram [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).